# Get the number of goroutines waiting to write to / read from a channel (for profiling)

Tags: go, profiling, channel, goroutine

To profile my app, I want to know how many goroutines are waiting to write to or read from a channel; I can't find anything relevant in the [`reflect` package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/).

I can maintain an explicit counter of course, but I'd expect golang runtime to know that, so I try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

So, is there a way to do that without maintaining the counter manually?

Answer (score 1):

To track overall load you are probably looking for `runtime.NumGoroutine()`

https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumGoroutine

Though it's not exactly number of just blocked Go routines it should be very close to it and not exceed the `runtime.NumGoroutine() - GOMAXPROCS`

For **tracking Go routines per channel** you can do next:

1. Use https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#Do to mark routines with a specific channel.
2. Use `http/pprof` to get information on current profile and parse output - see this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414527/1975086. Or maybe you can look into `http/pprof` and find out how it gets the information so you can get it within your app in typed way.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem: obviously I have more than one channel in my app, and goroutines are waiting on different channels, so I need to see which channels they are waiting for, so I'll be able to spot bottlenecks.

Comment: You don't need to use `net/http/pprof` to get a "block" profile, you can do the same directly from `runtime/pprof` if you don't want the http handler.