# How to determine which goroutine is blocking execution?

Tags: go, pprof, pgx

all.

I have a small parser that writes found data to Postgres, as database framework I use https://github.com/jackc/pgx.

I write parsed data to an unbuffered channel from various goroutines.

I have special goroutine where I read data from this channel and write it to the database.

I'm debugging an application and it hangs forever sometime after (perhaps waiting for a free connection to a database in the pool).

How to determine which goroutine is blocking execution?

I've heard that there is a pprof, but I never used it.
Thanks.

minimal example:
I've struct like this

```golang
ParsingResults struct {
    parser  DataParser
    data []*common.Data
    err     error
}
```

in separate goroutine I init unbuffered channel like this:

```golang
results = make(chan *ParsingResults)
```

then I start various goroutines, where I run parsers:

```golang
go fetcher.Parse(results)
```

each parser gathers data and passes it to the channel like this:

```golang
var (
    results chan<- *ParsingResults
    pageResults *ParsingResults
)
results <- pageResults
if pageResults.err != nil {
    return
}

time.Sleep(p.provider.DelayBetweenPages)
```

and in a separate goroutine such a function is launched:

```golang
func (fetcher *Fetcher) waitForResults(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case results := <-fetcher.resultsChannel:
            provider := results.parser.GetProvider()
            if results.err != nil {
                common.Logger.Errorw("failed to fetch data from provider",
                    "provider", provider.Url,
                    "error", results.err)
                continue
            }
            data := fetcher.removeDuplicates(results.data)
            common.Logger.Infow("fetched some data",
                "provider", provider.Url,
                "rows_count", len(results.data),
                "unique_rows_count", len(data))
            _, err := fetcher.Repo.SaveFetchedData(ctx, data)
            if err != nil {
                common.Logger.Errorw("failed to save fetched data",
                    "provider", provider.Url,
                    "error", err)
                continue
            }
            common.Logger.Infow("fetched data were saved successfully",
                "provider", provider.Url,
                "rows_count", len(results.data),
                "unique_rows_count", len(data))
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            common.Logger.Infow("for debugging's sake! waiting for some data to arrive!")
        }
    }
}
```

the data is stored in the database in this function:

```golang
func (repo *Repository) SaveFetchedData(ctx context.Context, rows []*common.Data) (int64, error) {
    if len(rows) == 0 {
        return 0, nil
    }

    baseQB := sq.Insert(db.DataTableName).
        Columns(saveFetchedDataCols...).
        PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

    batch := &pgx.Batch{}
    for _, p := range rows {
        curQB := baseQB.Values(p.Row1, p.Row2, sq.Expr("NOW()"))
        curQuery, curArgs, err := curQB.ToSql()

        if err != nil {
            return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate SQL query: %w", err)
        }
        batch.Queue(curQuery, curArgs...)
    }

    br := repo.pool.SendBatch(ctx, batch)
    ct, err := br.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to run SQL query batch: %w", err)
    }

    return ct.RowsAffected(), nil
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking about recomendations for tools/software is off-topic here. I suggest you edit your question to include more details of your problem with a [mre] or try a different forum to ask in.

Comment: you can use https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool to pool in that repo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414527/4466350

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace

Comment: Look at the stack trace which shows all blocking goroutines

Comment: It'd useful to add your main func in order to determine your "sync" logic. According to the question all the "producers" and "consumers" are run in separated goroutines, since "...it hangs forever sometimes..."  it's worth to consider how the process of waiting for the completion of all routines is built.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out full goroutine stack in pprof. So the error was that I did not release the connection from the pool after processing the result of the batch request.
Therefore, 10 requests passed, the pool was completely filled and the execution thread was blocked. Guys, y'all are the best. Thanks for the help.